# Updating an array using pointers instead of indexing

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, mips

I'm working on an assignment where we have to translate a piece of MIPS-code into C (although it should be easy to understand this problem even if you don't know MIPS, given the code I've written in C). I can't contact my teacher, because we are a huge class and I know he gets more than enough e-mails on a daily basis, which is why I'm turning to here.

I'm trying to use function copycodes() in order to copy the ascii codes of each character in text1 and text2 into list1 and list2, so that they can be printed by a provided function.

I'm basically done and it seems to me like it should work, however I keep getting *Segmentation fault (core dumped)*-error, or it only loops twice but does not print anything from the lists. I keep going through my code and changing little things, but I've been looking all day and I can't seem to find where my knowledge is flawed.

The program was written by my teacher, apart from function copycodes(), function work() and public variables at the top. All comments, where they occur (in the mips code too), are also written by me.

As mentioned I was also provided with MIPS-code representing how the solution should be implemented, which has been included in comments in it's respective places in my code below. I've tried to stay close to the MIPS-code, hence why the variables in copycodes() have the names of the registers used by the assembly code.

Here is how I have done it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Assembly code:
/*
.data


text1:    .asciiz "This is a string."
text2:    .asciiz "Yet another thing."

.align  2
list1:  .space 80   
list2:  .space 80   
count:  .word  0    
*/

//C translation:

char* text1 = "This is a string.";
char* text2 = "Yet another thing.";


//int* list1;
//int* list2; 
int list1 [80]; //Still passes the pointer of list1[0] to copycodes
int list2 [80];

int count = 0;


void printlist(const int* lst){
  printf("ASCII codes and corresponding characters.\n");
  while(*lst != 0){
    printf("0x%03X '%c' ", *lst, (char)*lst);
    lst++;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void endian_proof(const char* c){
    printf("\nEndian experiment: 0x%02x,0x%02x,0x%02x,0x%02x\n", 
        (int)*c,(int)*(c+1), (int)*(c+2), (int)*(c+3));

}




//Assembly code:
/*
copycodes:
loop:

    #   a0 is text (.asciiz)
    #   a1 is list (.space)
    #   a2 is count (.word)

    lb  $t0,0($a0)  # byte t0 = from a0 (text1/text2) 
    beq $t0,$0,done # branch done if (t0 == 0)
    sw  $t0,0($a1)  # else word t0 = a1 (list1/list2) 

    addi    $a0,$a0,1   # a0++
    addi    $a1,$a1,4   # a1+4 

    lw      $t1,0($a2)  # load word from a2 into t1
    addi    $t1,$t1,1   # increment t1 by 1
    sw      $t1,0($a2)  # store word from t1 to a2
    j       loop        # jump to top
done:
    jr  $ra
*/

void copycodes(char* a0, int* a1, int* a2){


    char t0 = *a0; //load byte from where a0 is pointing into t0)

    while(t0 != 0) //until end of string
    {

        //sw        $t0,0($a1)      // else word t0 = a1 (list1/list2) 

        //t0 = *a1;
        *a1 = t0; //store word from t0 to where a1 is pointing )



        //addi      $a0,$a0,1       // a0++
        //addi      $a1,$a1,4       // a1+4 

        a0++;       //increments pointer of text (a0)
        a1 += 4;    //increments pointer of list (a1) (in the mips code this is incremented by 4)


        //lw        $t1,0($a2)      // load word from t1 into a2
        //addi      $t1,$t1,1       // increment t1 by 1
        //sw        $t1,0($a2)      // store word from t1 to a2

        int countValue = *a2; //set countValue equal to value at pointer a2
        countValue++;         //increment counter
        *a2 = countValue;     // Set counter (at register a2) to the incremented value

    }


}
void work(){

    copycodes(text1,list1,&count);
    copycodes(text2,list2,&count);

}
int main(void){
    work();

    printf("\nlist1: ");
    printlist(list1);   //[20]);
    printf("\nlist2: ");
    printlist(list2);   //);
    printf("\nCount = %d\n", count);

  endian_proof((char*) &count);
}
```

I've seen similar questions such as [Homework: Making an array using pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097161/homework-making-an-array-using-pointers)
But it looks to me as though they are doing fundamentally the same thing regarding the pointers? I thought for a while that perhaps my problem is the amount by which I'm incrementing a0 and a1, but I have not yet been able to find anythig that describes this problem.

**Edit:**
I might aswell add that the desired output is:

list1: ASCII codes and corresponding characters. 0x054 'T' 0x068 'h' 0x069 'i' 0x073 's' 0x020 ' ' 0x069 'i' 0x073 's' 0x020 ' ' 0x061 'a' 0x020 ' ' 0x073 's' 0x074 't' 0x072 'r' 0x069 'i' 0x06E 'n' 0x067 'g' 0x02E '.'

list2: ASCII codes and corresponding characters. 0x059 'Y' 0x065 'e' 0x074 't' 0x020 ' ' 0x061 'a' 0x06E 'n' 0x06F 'o' 0x074 't' 0x068 'h' 0x065 'e' 0x072 'r' 0x020 ' ' 0x074 't' 0x068 'h' 0x069 'i' 0x06E 'n' 0x067 'g' 0x02E '.' Count = 35

Endian experiment: 0x23,0x00,0x00,0x00

Comment: `a1 += 4;` should be `a1 += 1;`.

Comment: `t0` needs to be updated within the `while` loop, or it will always stay the same (first character from the string).  Or, just use `*a0` instead.

Comment: @melpomene Yet it says `addi      $a1,$a1,4       // a1+4 ` What exactly do you mean?

Comment: When you add an integer to a pointer in C, it adds multiples of the size of whatever that pointer type pointer points to -- not just 1.  (eg. adding 6 to an `int *` gives an address that is `6 * sizeof(int)` more than the original address).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to melpomene and Dmitri for finding the problems!

I had indeed incremented a1 incorrectly and also forgotten to update t0 inside the while loop. I ended up with a solution completely without t0.

Here is the updated function:

```js
void copycodes(char* a0, int* a1, int* a2){


    //char t0 = *a0; //load byte from where a0 is pointing into t0)

    while(*a0 != 0) //until end of string
    {

        //sw        $t0,0($a1)      // else word t0 = a1 (list1/list2) 

        //t0 = *a0;
        *a1 = *a0; //store word from t0 to where a1 is pointing )



        //addi      $a0,$a0,1       // a0++
        //addi      $a1,$a1,4       // a1+4 

        a0++;       //increments pointer of text (a0)
        a1++;    //increments pointer of list (a1) (in the mips code this is incremented by 4)


        //lw        $t1,0($a2)      // load word from t1 into a2
        //addi      $t1,$t1,1       // increment t1 by 1
        //sw        $t1,0($a2)      // store word from t1 to a2

        int countValue = *a2; //set countValue equal to value at pointer a2
        countValue++;         //increment counter
        *a2 = countValue;     // Set counter (at register a2) to the incremented value

    }


}
```

Comment: Using meaningful variable names aids in understanding code.  Perhaps `void copycodes(const char* a0_text, int* a1_list, int* a2_count)`?